Largest value for $z$ so that $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$ where $n$ is a constant and, $x \leq y \leq z$? All positive integers
What is the largest integer value for $z$ so that $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$ where $n$ is a constant positive integer; $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive integers; and $x\leq y\leq z$?
The inequality $x\leq y\leq z$ leads to the following boundaries.

$n+1 \leq x \leq 3n$
$\lfloor \frac{nx}{x-n} \rfloor +1 \leq y \leq \frac{2nx}{n-x}$ when $n+1 \leq x \leq 2n$
$x \leq y \leq \frac{2nx}{n-x}$ when $2n < x \leq 3n$

What I did was I assumed that $x$, $y$, and $z$ could be real positive numbers, and made $\frac{1}{z}$ a function of $x$ and $y$, then tried to use methods in multivariate calculus. The function that I got was
$f \left( x,y \right) = \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}$.
To make $z$ as large as possible, we would need to minimize the function, which would mean maximizing $\frac{1}{x}$ and/or $\frac{1}{y}$, which would mean minimizing $x$ and $y$ themselves.
For the third condition, analysis is pretty straight-forward as minimizing $y$ would just mean letting $y=x$, making the function depend on only $x$, so we can analyze it using standard methods in calculus. In summary, I got that the derivative is negative, so the function decreases as x increases, so we want the smallest choice for $x$ which would be $2n+1$, and since $x=y$, we eventually get that $z=n\left( 2n+1 \right)$.
My problem is on the second condition due to the floor function.
I was able to determine that when the inside part of the floor function is not an integer, the derivative is positive. I was also able to determine that as we increase in values for $x$ that make the floor an integer, the function value also increases. My problem is that for integer values of $x$, sometimes the floor part will be an integer, and sometimes not an integer. So, I'm having difficulty justifying that evaluating when $x=n+1$ and $y=\lfloor \frac{nx}{x-n} \rfloor +1$ will give the largest value for $z$.
Any helps or ideas as to how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated :)

$$\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n^2+n+1} + \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n^2+n+1)}$$ gives a bigger value for $z$

@jjagmath That's the same as the question asks (i.e. justifying that the largest value for $z$ comes from $x=n+1$ and $y=\left\lfloor\frac{nx}{x-n}\right\rfloor+1$).

We have $xyz=n(xy+yz+zx)$ so
$$xy+z(x+y)|xyz$$
$$xy+z(x+y)|xy(xy+z(x+y))-(x+y)xyz$$
$$=x^2 y^2$$
Hence
$$xy+z(x+y) \le x^2 y^2$$
$$z \le \frac{xy(xy-1)}{x+y}$$
And this is an equality for the example jjagmath and Dietrich suggest, so I suspect this is optimal. In the 2 dimensional case the proof proceeds easily enough from the corresponding inequality.

@ZoeAllen You should write that up as an answer. If you let $y=nx/(x-n)+1$, the maximum of $\frac{xy(xy-1)}{x+y}$ on the interval $n+1\le x\le 2n$ happens at $x=n+1$. And when $x\ge 2n+1$, the best we could do anyways is $z=n(2n+1)<n(n+1)(n^2+n+1)$, which finishes the proof.

@VarunVejalla I'm struggling to follow that argument. Perhaps you should write it up.

@ZoeAllen I think you're struggling to follow that argument because it isn't right haha. You'd need $y=nx/(x-n)$, not $y=nx/(x-n)+1$, in order to show what I claimed above.

@VarunVejalla Thank you for that explanation. I did not think of using that divisibility trick. I'm still a bit stuck though with justifying to check the endpoints ($x=n+1$ and $x=2n$).
Also, I played around with what you did and came up with an inequality that is smaller when $x \geq n+1$. To the inequality that you came up with, the one right after "Hence", I multiplied both sides by $n$, so that the left side becomes $xyz$, and dividing both sides by $xy$ results in $z \leq nxy$.
I'm still unsure as to how to justify checking the endpoints though.
